# Set gridview button text from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview, datatable

I am trying to bind a gridview from code behind. One of the columns contain a button. The text of that button should change depending on the content loaded in the row.For example based on the content the button should say either **publish** or **unpublish** . Here is what i have done.

The aspx code for gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">

                          <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sub Category" DataField="Sub Category"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:ImageField HeaderText="Image" DataImageUrlField="Image" ControlStyle-Height="39px"
                                    ControlStyle-Width="150px">
                                </asp:ImageField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Start Date" DataField="Start Date"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Expiry Date" DataField="Expiry Date"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Status" DataTextField="Status" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="publishButton_Click" />
                            </Columns>
                                                    </asp:GridView>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
 GridView1.DataSource = fillOfferGridView(nodeid);
            GridView1.DataBind();
}
DataTable fillOfferGridView(int nodeId)
        {
            Document next = new Document(nodeId);
            Button bf = new Button();
            DataTable dtOfferDetails = new DataTable();
            dtOfferDetails.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dtOfferDetails.Columns.Add("Sub Category", typeof(string));
            dtOfferDetails.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(string));
            dtOfferDetails.Columns.Add("Start Date", typeof(string));
            dtOfferDetails.Columns.Add("Expiry Date", typeof(string));
            dtOfferDetails.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(Button));

            foreach (Document offer in next.Children)
            {
                DataRow dr = dtOfferDetails.NewRow();
                //string myOfferName = offer.GetProperty("offerName").Value;
                //string offerNodeName = offer.Name;
                //string offerurl = offer.NiceUrl;
                //string offerType = offer.GetProperty("offerType").Value;
                //string offerImage = offer.GetProperty("offerImage").Value;
                dr["Name"] = offer.getProperty("offerName").Value;
                dr["Sub Category"] = offer.getProperty("offerType").Value;
                dr["Image"] =  ResolveUrl(offer.getProperty("offerImage").ToString());
                dr["Start Date"] = offer.getProperty("offerLaunchDate").Value;
                dr["Expiry Date"] = offer.getProperty("offerExpiryDate").Value;
                if (offer.Published == true)
                {
                    bf.Text = "Unpublish";
                }
                else
                {
                    bf.Text = "Publish";
                }
                dr["Status"] = bf;
                dtOfferDetails.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dtOfferDetails;
        }
```

but when i run the code instead of the desired text i get **system.web.ui.webcontrols.button** on the button. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dr["Status"] = bf.Text;
```

if you place button in your Status field DataGrid just calls its ToString() method ans as result you've got system.web.ui.webcontrols.button text instead of button caption.

Even more. You don't need create new Button inside your code. Just write:

```
if (offer.Published == true)
                {
                    dr["Status"] = "Unpublish";
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Status"] = "Publish";
                }
```

Comment: Also change dtOfferDetails.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(Button)); to  dtOfferDetails.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string)).

Answer (score 2):

Ammend this line

```
   dr["Status"] = bf;
```

to

```
    dr["Status"] = bf.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line needs to be:

```
dr["Status"] = bf.Text;
```